# C# chart adding data in a for-int loop

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, charts

i need help with this one, i have created a chart in wpf, and in my c# i have the following:

```
((ColumnSeries)callLogs.Series[0]).ItemsSource =
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{

      for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
      {
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>(callHour[i], callCounter[i])
      }
};
```

Now the above statement doesn't work.

The variables callHour and callCounter are arrays that pull the needed data from the database and they work fine, i just need a way of adding data to the graph by the amount of values stored in the array, if that makes sense?

In other words instead of using this method:

```
((ColumnSeries)callLogs.Series[0]).ItemsSource =
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>(callHour[0], callCounter[0]),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>(callHour[1], callCounter[1]),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>(callHour[2], callCounter[2]),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>(callHour[3], callCounter[3]),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>(callHour[4], callCounter[4]),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>(callHour[5], callCounter[5]),
    ...};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really have to use array initializer? Just define array first and then add the values to it using `for` loop

Comment: Yes the array works fine, ive tested the outputs. My problem here is that the graph doesnt want to look when i put the for int loop in

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found any solution, then create an array of KeyValuePair object first and then assign it to ItemSource:

```
 var items = new KeyValuePair<string, int>[counter];
        for(var i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            items[i] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(callHour[i], callCounter[i]);
        };
 (ColumnSeries)callLogs.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items;
```